# How can I count the same fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm making a query to get the stages of a case. So Now I have three cases with 3 stages (the last stage inserted in the table user_case_stage).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.id)
       c.id,
       f.name
FROM schema.user a
  JOIN schema.intern_user b ON a.id = b."userId"
  JOIN schema.user_case c ON b.id = c."internUserId"
  JOIN schema.user_case_stage d ON c.id = d."userCaseId"
  JOIN schema.stage f ON d."stageId" = f.id
WHERE b.id = 1
ORDER BY c.id,d."createdAt" DESC
```

Result:

```
caseId      stageName
  1         "Pasive"
  6         "Closed"
  7         "Closed"
```

But I want something to count by stageName like this:

```
total      stageName
  1         "Pasive"
  2         "Closed"
```

Comment: Use ```SELECT COUNT(name_of_fields) ```

Comment: I tried but is not working like this: (It shows me on total only 1 not 2)

SELECT
DISTINCT ON
(c.id)
c.id,
COUNT (f.name) AS total
FROM cial.user a
JOIN cial.intern_user b
ON a.id = b."userId"
JOIN cial.user_case c
ON b.id = c."internUserId"
JOIN cial.user_case_stage d
ON c.id = d."userCaseId"
JOIN cial.stage f
ON d."stageId" = f.id
WHERE b.id = 1
GROUP BY
c.id,
d."createdAt"
ORDER BY 
c.id,
d."createdAt" DESC

Comment: I think it is normal beacause `DISTINCT` mean if you have already a value that will not be displayed once. that display each result once.

Comment: Remove `DISTINCT` that will display all grouped by or ordered by.

Answer (score 0):

assumed your logic is correct , since you didn't provide any information, here is how you can do it:

```
SELECT   
    f.name
    , count(distinct c.id) total
FROM schema.user a
JOIN schema.intern_user b ON a.id = b."userId"
JOIN schema.user_case c ON b.id = c."internUserId"
JOIN schema.user_case_stage d ON c.id = d."userCaseId"
JOIN schema.stage f ON d."stageId" = f.id
WHERE b.id = 1
group by f.name
```

Comment: This works but I only want to return the last stage inserted on the table user_case_stage thats why on my query im using the ORDER BY with d."createdAt" DESC
How I can do that?

Comment: @frank that order by just sort data doesn't pick the last row, just show the last rows at the beginning. so you have to provide sample data ,preferably in a fiddle as well.